# Basic authentication ssl and NTLM NET 5 API

Tags: c#, ssl, basic-authentication, .net-5, ntlm-authentication

How can I use basic authentication with ssl and NTLM at the same time in a NET 5 API?
The background of the question is the following: we are using a web UI which authenticates with NTLM (this should remain as it is); in the other hand, there is a biztalk client which needs to authenticate using basic authentication with ssl due to incompatibility with NTLM.

I'm searching information on how to accomplish it, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: BizTalk doesn't require basic authentication. It *does* support Windows authentication. What does `due to incompatibility with NTLM.` mean? Do you want to connect using the client's or the application pool/service's account? Are those accounts domain accounts?

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer. We have a problem when authenticating from BzTalk, if we call the api from a rest client (Postman for example), the user is detected correctly. But when we send the request from BizTalk it takes the user of the IIS application pool. We need to authenticate with the client's  service account. Both are domain accounts

Comment: In other words, you want to impersonate the client. ASP.NET always supported impersonation. ASP.NET Core [requires some extra middleware code for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation)